# Create a program that can identify outliers based on +- 2s for a regression equation using 3 independant variables which are columns in csv file

Tags: r, csv, object, outliers

I am trying to create a program that can identify outliers based on +- 2s for a regression equation using 3 independant variables which are columns in csv file.

I have no idea where to start in terms of coding, I have tried to get R to look at the 3 columns that correspond to my independant variables so I can find the summary data of the equation but I keep getting error messages.

I have attached the data as well as a screenshot of my code so far. I would really appreciate any advice anyone can give me.

Here is my code:

```
data<-read.csv("Project_data_Cars1.csv")
str(data)

data$Make<-as.numeric(data$Make)
data$Model<-as.numeric(data$Model)
data$Trim<-as.numeric(data$Trim)
data$Type<-as.numeric(data$Type)

library(leaps)

leap<-regsubsets(Price~., data=data, nvmax = 5, nvbest = 2)
bestfitSummary<-summary(leap)

bestfitSummary$outmat

RegFun<-lm(formula = Price ~ Cyl + Trim + Cruise + Mileage, data=data)
summary(RegFun)
```

The error message is:

```
Error in summary(RegFun) : object RegFun not found
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to create a [mcve] so that we can run your code, reproduce your problem, and help you. You can use `dput` to create a  usable toy dataset.

Comment: I wasn't able to attach the excel file, but my dependant variable, price, in in the second column, and my 3 independent variables are in columns 5, 7, and 10.

Comment: I know you can't attach the excel file; I want you to use `dput` to create an example dataset that we can use. If you don't do this, how can we run and debug your code?

Comment: Not sure how to use dput but I'll do some research and try to make an example dataset asap, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by your question, but if you're looking for outliers in your data you can do something like this:

```
#initialize data
dat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 100,ncol = 2))
names(dat) <- c("value","outlier")

#generate normally distributed random variable
dat$value <- c(rnorm(50,1,100),rnorm(50,1000,100000))

#summary statistics
mean <- mean(dat$value)
sd <- sd(dat$value)

#if else statement
dat$outlier <- ifelse(dat$value > (mean + (2*sd)) | 
                        dat$value < (mean - (2*sd)),1,0)

#select outliers

dat[dat$outlier == 1,]

#console output 

       value outlier
55  195283.9       1
64 -172011.6       1
65 -143934.8       1
73  188834.3       1
76 -147519.1       1
95  152978.7       1
```